# A way to redirect keypresses from TWebBrowser to the ParentForm

Tags: delphi, focus, webbrowser-control, sendkeys, twebbrowser

First question. Help format it, if needed, please.

***Context***
I have a TWebBrowser in the main form that is used to behave like it was a printer.
So I load some HTML text in it as user do some commands in the real printer...
I want the user to be able to click and select text from the WebBrowser.

***Problem***
When the user clicks in the WebBrowser some of the shortcuts registered from the actions don't work anymore. For example, there is an action with shortcut `F7`. If the user clicks in the WebBrowser and presses F7, it does not invoke my shortcut.
I know that this is by design of the WebBrowser.

So, I thought: I want to send every key combination back to the form.
The question is: How?
If it was another control, I could use a `perform(WM_KeyDown,...)` in the `OnKeyDown` event.

Alternatives or suggestions would be appreciated too. I am very tired these past 2 days, so I could be missing something.

Comment: Maybe this will show you the way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446440/how-can-i-avoid-refresh-with-twebbrowser/3447422#3447422

Comment: +1 @daemon_x using the `IHTMLDocument2::onkeydown` event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752616%28VS.85%29.aspx) is the way to go.

Comment: @RRUZ - the questions are different, so repost (or slightly modify) your answer here to get more upvotes :) I gave you one there because I can't believe it's even possible to do this. And it works fine (I'll implement it very next day to one of my applications). Thanks

Comment: @daemon_x, if you can modify the original answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446440/how-can-i-avoid-refresh-with-twebbrowser/3447422#3447422) to fit with this question, feel free to elaborate a new answer ;)

Comment: @RRUZ @daemon_x, many thanks. I will take time to test it. Sorry I didn't found it before. I searched and read about more than 15 questions and answers about TWebBrowser, did not found that one. Thanks again.

Comment: @RRUZ @daemon_x Worked for me. Just a thing. As explained, in my case, I am the one that supply the webbrowser with HTML. So I used the onDocumentComplete to assign the event handler instead of onNavigateComplete2. Would any of you answer it here so I could accept the answer? Thanks. Also Thanks to @Johan who revised text of the question. I am pleased with that kind of corrections. :)

Answer (score 4):

Derivate TWebBrowser with an implementation of `IDocHostUIHandler` or use the famous [EmbeddedWB](http://www.bsalsa.com/)

Implement the interface with an event `OnTranslateAccelerator` called in `TranslateAccelerator`

Set the event on your brwoser instance

Detect your key(s) like this:

```
function TBrowserPageIE.DoTranslateAccelerator(const lpMsg: PMSG; const pguidCmdGroup: PGUID; const nCmdID: DWORD): HRESULT;
begin
  result := S_FALSE;

  if lpMsg.message = WM_KEYDOWN then begin
    if lpMsg.wParam = VK_F7 then begin
      // do something here...
      result := S_OK;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hi Matthias. I will take the time to test that way. Thanks. I am avoiding EmbeddedWB for some reasons. I never worked with it, so I gone to forum to see what about it. I found that not many of the questions are being answered there. As it is open-source, I could take the code myself and work on it. But I am involved with others open-sources components and have not much time this exactly now. So I fear take some responsibility that I will not be able to accomplish. For example, some people are saying that it is not IE9 compatible...

Comment: Can I accept more than one answer? Cause I am using @daemon_x @RRUZ suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

An option that I tested and worked is to trap the key_code on HTML/javascript and then send that to the form using changing the document title. I will let it here hoping that help someone...

You will need add the javascript to trap the keys in the Header of the HTML page like this:

```
<script = ''javascript''>
  function keypresed() {
    var tecla=window.event.keyCode;

    document.title = "Command"+tecla;
    event.keyCode=0;
    event.returnValue=false;
  }
  document.onkeydown=keypresed;
</script>
```

Then in Webbrowser you use the onTitleChangeEvent to use the key.

```
var
 s:string;
begin
  if Copy(Text,0,7) = 'Command' then
  begin
    //get the key...
    s:= Copy(Text,8,Length(Text));

    // if before the webbrowser get the focus edit1 was the focused control, you will need remove that focus first...
    dummy.setfocus; 
    edit1.setfocus;

    //perform keydown
    keybd_event(StrToInt(s), 1,0,0)
  end;
end;
```

Well, this can be used to perform any other custom command. :)

Comment: A very good solution and 'trick'. In my case, I needed VK_F11 and VK_ESCAPE for Fullscreen display and Fullscreen exit.